# Extending "on click" function as click.'something'?

Tags: jquery, onclick

I found the code below in a wordpress theme I'm working with. I'm trying to understand the use for code "testClick" in click.testClick statement. If I remove it, it works the same. Does it serve any purpose? 
The testClick word does not exist anywhere in the site.

Is this possibly a trigger that can be used to extend the function? Can someone point me to some documentation in this regard, or provide an example of its use? I'm still new to jquery.

```
<a href="#" class="test_click">Test Click</a>

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  e( "body" ).on( "click.testClick", ".test_click", function() { 
    alert("clicked!");
  })
});
```

works just like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  e( "body" ).on( "click", ".test_click", function() { 
    alert("clicked!");
  })
});
```

Comment: I think that is event.target. I found this doc http://api.jquery.com/event.target/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). Event namespaces allow you to remove event listeners without removing all the event listeners on an element:

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
>   removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple"
>   defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
>   click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
>   removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without
>   disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
>   are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
>   name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are
>   reserved for jQuery's use. This will likely be used primarily by plugin authors who wish to handle tasks differently depending on the event namespace used.

Example:

```
<button>display event.namespace</button>
<p></p>

<script>
$( "p" ).on( "test.something", function( event ) {
  alert( event.namespace );
});
$( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "p" ).trigger( "test.something" );
});
</script>
```